# How can you set path of match with MemoryRouter and Jest? (not location or history)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jestjs

please forgive me if there is a duplicate.

I know MemoryRouter has initialEntries and initialIndex, so you can set path and etc for "location" and "history". However "match" is not getting updated... I need to set "match" for my react app and Jest tests.

When I try,

```
<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/hello']} initialIndex={0}>
      <Hello store={store} />
</MemoryRouter>
```

I am getting

```
match: { path: '/', url: '/', params: {} ... },
location: { path: '/hello', pathname: '/', ... },
history: { ..., location: { path: '/hello', pathname: '/', ... }}
```

I wonder if there is a way to set match. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide your whole file example? Wasting an entire day here and yet no solution.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can wrap your `<Hello store={store} />` component with `<Route ... />` component like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// later in tests

<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/home']}>      
  <Route component={props => <HomeComponent {...props} />} path="/home" /> 
</MemoryRouter>
```

Then you should have access to proper `match` object by `props`.